# Where to place package development directory and files?

Tags: r

I'm developing a package here at work from a number of functions that I've written. Once I build the package, I'll put the binary in a local package repository I've created on a company network drive, using a process described by Dirk in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905650/creating-a-local-cran-repository).

Question: **Should my package dev folder be located in my package repository? If so, where?**

I couldn't find much about this in the [Creating a Package Tutorial](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf), nor in the [R Administrator Guide](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Setting-up-a-package-repository).

Comment: What is the package dev folder?  Also Dirk's answer is sound, however, it is nearly 2 years old.  Rstudio can make this task very nice as seen in this video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScV7XXlBZww

Comment: I just mean the folder from which I'll be using RStudio to build the windows binary. I realise my working directory in RStudio could be any folder at all, but is there normally a folder in the package repository where this stuff would sit?

Comment: This can be named anything you want.  I called mine gits, so my path to a package is:  `"C://Users//trinker//gits//package.name"`.  Devtools makes light work of the install as well as I then can use: `install("C://Users//trinker//gits//package.name")`.  Not sure if what I've said is helpful, hopefully it is.

Comment: A single forward slash will do, no need for //.

Comment: Good call Dirk as a Windows user I often forget which way is which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not matter where your package development directories live.

That said, I think it's a good idea to keep them separate from binary package repositories, because they are conceptually quite different, and generally you should be able to delete a repo and re-generate it from sources.