# R set up local package repository

Tags: r, r-package

I'm trying to set up a local repository on my local network, following these instructions : [Creating a local R package repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905650/creating-a-local-r-package-repository).

And I'm getting the same problem as the one described in the "Update" paragraph of : [install.packages errors: Troubleshooting local repo usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813924/install-packages-errors-troubleshooting-local-repo-usage), 
(Even if the question is marked as solved, there is no available solution provided)

I've put my package into the folder:

```
"S:/outils/packages R/bin/windows/contrib/3.2"
```

As per Dirk's instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905650/creating-a-local-r-package-repository) SO, I've run the following commands:

```
setwd("S:/outils/packages R/bin/windows/contrib/3.2")
tools::write_PACKAGES(".", type="win.binary")
list.files()
[1] "BayesTree_0.3-1.3.zip" "Epi_2.0.zip"           "PACKAGES"              "PACKAGES.gz"
```

I ran the following command in order to point to my new local repository. I copied and pasted this command from the `repo` paragraph of the `options` help page :

```
local({r <- getOption("repos"); r["CRAN"] <- 'file://S:/Outils/packages R'; options(repos = r)})
```

And when I try to install some packages I get an error :

```
install.packages("Epi")
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'S:/Outils/packages R/src/contrib/PACKAGES', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

I tried to put the "PACKAGES" and the "PACKAGES.gz" files into the `S:/outils/packages R/bin/windows/contrib/folder` or into `S:/outils/packages R/`, without any success.

Answer (score 1):

If you read to the bottom of Dirk's answer, you'll see he mentions the wonderful [`drat`](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) package. This takes care of the pain you're experiencing and creates the PACKAGES.gz file and associated paths pain free.

As a bonus, `drat` ties in with github.io free of charge.