# Install an R package directly from a URL for the package source

Tags: r

I would like to install a package directly from a URL for the package source. I want to do this to make it easy for people to test a pre-release version of the package which should not be widely (or permanently) available.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source) is a similar question but it is different because it only describes how to install from local files not general URLs.

For the sake of this question I will use a link to the `boot` package source. Reading `?install.packages` particularly the description of the `pkgs` argument suggests:

```
install.packages(
  "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/boot/boot_1.3-7.tar.gz", 
  repos = NULL, type = "source"
)
```

However this fails with:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 
  ‘http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/boot/boot_1.3-7.tar.gz’ 
  had non-zero exit status
```

Suggesting that the URL is being interpreted as the package name, not its location. 
We can work around this with the following two step procedure:

```
download.file(
  "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/boot/boot_1.3-7.tar.gz", 
  "boot"
)
install.packages("boot", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

But I would prefer to do this with a single call to `install.packages` only; and since `install.packages` is capable of downloading files anyway I feel this should be possible.

Comment: The package is not being found in your original call because it is not there. It is `boot_1.3-9.tar.gz` in that directory.

Comment: @SimonO101 sorry that was a mistake I made in writing the question. Fixing it does not change the behaviour unfortunately.

Comment: Why not set up the directory in which you store the source package as a repository? [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905650/creating-a-local-r-package-repository), though you'd likely want to substitute `type="source"` for `type="win.binary"`

Comment: Good. Now that I understand what you're after, I'll make that an answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`install.packages` now works with http URLs (not https yet)  as of 3.1.1. This works for me:

```
install.packages("http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/colorout_1.1-0.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
```

Edit: As of R 3.2.0, `https` is builtin via libcurl. This should work now:

```
install.packages("https://github.com/hadley/devtools/archive/v1.7.0.tar.gz",
                 repos=NULL, method="libcurl")
```

Edit: As of R 3.2.2, `https` should work with default options assuming libcurl support was compiled in.

Edit 2016-04-20: There may be some issues downloading packages hosted on S3, but `method='wget'` seems to work for those for now.

Comment: This method failed with a '403 Forbidden' error when `install.packages()` tried to download the file using `download.file()`. Not sure if libcurl support was compiled in but `devtools::install_url()` suggested by @G. Grothendieck works with no problem.

Comment: That sounds like a authentication issue. What url are you trying to download?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be but for a different URL (maybe where the file is actually hosted).  Compare `install.packages("https://bitbucket.org/kleinstein/logminer/downloads/pclogit_0.2.tar.gz")` to `devtools::install.packages("https://bitbucket.org/kleinstein/logminer/downloads/pclogit_0.2.tar.gz")`

Comment: That url redirects to `https://bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com/786fe3b9-c855-4ead-8e92-9a923307571e/downloads/198445c2-b162-4e7b-9de9-2a5def8c1e70/pclogit_0.2.tar.gz?Signature=rkSXfOUzDeYaOiA0s%2BcFOqA33jc%3D&Expires=1492645028&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIVFPT2YJYYZY3H4A&versionId=E0GlRikyD2HwjjssxYfoSos.KUV9jOtd&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22pclogit_0.2.tar.gz%22`. I think amazon is blocking base R's user agent and not devtools, because `install.packages(..., method='wget')` seems to work fine. Very weird though, you might want to report this to the R maintainers.

Comment: yes, `method="wget"` does work fine for me so install.packages is a good solution.  If you modify your answer to note that "wget" method may work better for some URLs I will upvote. :)

Answer (score 10):

See `?install_url` in the devtools package.

Answer (score 2):

Why not set up the directory in which you store the source package as a repository?

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905650/creating-a-local-r-package-repository) (though you'd likely want to substitute `type="source"` for the `type="win.binary"` in the code at that link).

Comment: This solves my problem. I had hoped that ``install.packages`` would be able to download and install packages outside a repository but reading the documentation closely I think this is not possible so I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the url is a github repository, try: `install_github()`

e.g.

```
library(devtools)

install_github("DeveloperName/PackageName")

# e.g. install_github("cran/seoR")
```