# How can I download R packages using FTP

Tags: r

I need to support an R environment on a Windows 7 PC that doesn't have internet access.

I'd like to download (to DVD, eventually) a current version of all ~ 5,000 packages to make available to users of R on this PC.

Is there an FTP script, or another good way, to download all of the zip files for the R packages?

I know there are daily updates to R, but one good day will be enough to get me started.

Comment: Gerry, if either of the answers below work for you, could you select one as the answer? Just click the tick mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Presumably you have an installation somewhere that does have internet access. I would just set that installation to download everything. There's an example at http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-package-automated-download/. Start R, and try this:

```
pkg.list = available.packages()
download.packages(pkgs = pkg.list, destdir = "E:\MyRPackages")
```

Once you have these files, copy them to some kind of portable media (thumb drive, hard drive, whatever) or burn a CD / DVD and take that to the standalone machine.

**Note**: there may be a reason this other machine was not connected to the internet. So be careful! Make sure the virus protection is up to date on the non-connected machine, and that your IT folks won't come down on you like a ton of bricks for transferring data this way.

Next, you need to point the standalone machine at the portable media or the CD / DVD. A simple way to do this is to redefine where R looks for the repository. See e.g. [Creating a local R package repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905650/creating-a-local-r-package-repository) for examples.

In your case, try something like this in R:

```
update.packages(repos="complete-path-to-portable-media",repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Comment: Awesome!  Working perfectly!  Exactly what I want.  Thank you!

Comment: @Gerry, if you could accept this answer that would be great. Just click the tick on the left.

Answer (score 2):

Use rsync to [create a mirror](http://cran.r-project.org/mirror-howto.html) and then install packages by pointing to your local mirror as the `repos` argument of `install.packages`. No need to make the repository publicly available. Specialize the path (e.g., to rsync based on `/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/`) to retrieve just the windows binaries (to a directory that you've created with similar structure `repos/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/`) if that's all that needs to be supported.

```
rsync -rtlzv --delete \
    cran.r-project.org::CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/ \
    repos/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm on windows, so I needed to find an rsync.  The free version at https://www.itefix.no/i2/content/cwrsync-free-edition seems to be working fine -- I'm downloading lots of debian packages at the moment.  So, just one more question: is there a way using rsync to just get the windows versions?  I don't see anything at teh CRAN Mirror HOWTO page.

Comment: I've elaborated a bit in my answer -- instead of rsync'ing from the root, rsync from the root of the windows contrib directory of the version of R you're interested in making available.

Comment: The first solution above is working perfectly, so I'm abandoning this solution for now.  I can see definite advantages with this approach if I needed to keep up to date versions, but I think I can get by with updating once a month or quarter, so I'm using the inside-R solution for now.