# error installing R libraries on Azure VM

Tags: r, azure, rstudio, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I'm unable to install R libraries on an Azure Data Science VM.

For example, I've tried installing RODBC using `install.packages("RODBC")` in both jupyter notebook and RStudio, but get this error:

> Warning message:
>   "unable to access index for repository https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-03-15/src/contrib:
>     Line starting 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-03-15/bin/windows/contrib/3.3:
>     cannot open URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-03-15/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/PACKAGES'"

When running the same command on my local machine I get:

> install.packages("RODBC")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/j/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/RODBC_1.3-15.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 831635 bytes (812 KB)
>   downloaded 812 KB
>   package ‘RODBC’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Why is RStudio trying to connect to a dead link at mran.microsoft.com?

EDIT

Just realised that I can install libraries manually as per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279190/offline-installation-of-packages-in-rstudio/22335753#22335753), but it would be good to be able to use `install.packages`.

Comment: The VM has Microsoft R installed. This is a fork of R that includes some multi threading, etc. It has its own repositories (MRAN) that are synced with CRAN - but using 'snapshots' which are meant to keep things reproducible.

Comment: so the easiest way to fix this would be to install regular R? or can I configure RStudio to point to a different source, i.e. CRAN?

Comment: That would work but without experience with this pre-set-up VM, I can't say if that would break anything. Microsoft R does have certain advantages. But you could install Cran R too and just tell Rstudio to use that one.

Comment: sounds like a good solution, thanks

Comment: Coincidentally, I happened to use Microsoft R today, and it worked with Cran repos https://mran.microsoft.com/#change-repos