# Unable to install RTextTools in R Language

Tags: r, installation, package

I am using RStudio for R Language but when i tried to install `RTextTools` Error appear

> package 'RTextTools' is not available (for R version 3.5.3)

I have also downloaded all packages from repository but don't know how to manually add packages.

To download manual packages I have used this link:

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RTextTools/

Comment: Download an archive and manually install. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279190/offline-installation-of-packages-in-rstudio

Comment: I have downloaded and trying to install manually but failed

Comment: @AkhzarNazir In that case, editing your question to include what you tried to do to manually install and the error message you got would help us help you

Comment: Look at point 6 of the accepted answer in the first link.

Comment: I have resolved the issue Thanks you all