# How to bypass repos error when installing repository on internet disconnected machine?

Tags: r

I've found a number of different methods that can be used to install packages on a machine that isn't connected to the internet. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573952/how-can-i-download-r-packages-using-ftp/20574439#20574439) offers a fairly straightforward method to download the packages, transfer to the disconnected machine, and then to point the R installation at this custom repository.

After transferring the files, I ran the following command on the machine not connected to the internet:

```
update.packages(repos="C:/Users/username/Documents/R/R Repository/3.4",repos = NULL,type = "source")
```

After running the above line, I am getting the following error:

> Error in update.packages(repos = "C:/Users/username/Documents/R/R Repository/3.4",   : 
>   formal argument "repos" matched by multiple actual arguments

Another thing I noticed is that the downloaded packages are all ".tar.gz" files, and this is a windows machine (as was the machine in the linked post above). Could this be part of the problem?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have "repos =" twice in your call.  Take out "repos = NULL" and try it again.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This generated a new error, "Error in install.packages : argument 'pkgs' is missing, with no default."

Comment: it's probably looking for the list of package names like it would take in the normal connected install.packages() call.