# Unable to install R packages from a local repository

Tags: r

I'm working on Windows with R 3.6.3 which is the latest version my employer will allow me to install.  They also have a firewall that effectively blocks access to the CRAN.

I used the miniCRAN package to create a small repository of packages I want and their dependencies.  I constructed it from an older snapshot of the CRAN given my old version

```
library(miniCRAN)

mirror <- c(CRAN = "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/2020-03-02")  #old CRAN compatible with our R version

pkgs <- c("tidytext", "tidyr", "lexicon")    #etc for a long list of packages
pkgList <- pkgDep(pkgs, repos = mirror, type = "source", suggests = FALSE)

dir.create(pth <- file.path(tempdir(), "miniCRAN"))

makeRepo(pkgList, path = pth, repos = mirror, type = c("source", "win.binary"))
```

After running that I then had a directory called miniCRAN with subdirectories `bin` and `src`. The src/contrib folder that was created contains only tar.gz files.

I burned the miniCRAN directory to disc and then dropped it on a shared drive on our offline network. At the console in R Studio I then ran

```
tools::write_PACKAGES("file://c:/<path>/miniCRAN/src/contrib", type="source")
```

This creates a `PACKAGES` and a `PACKAGES.gz` file in the directory

However, when I try to install a package from this repository

```
install.packages("ggplot2", repos="file://c:/<path>/miniCRAN")
```

I get an error message

```
cannot open compressed file '//C:/Users/1129002260C/Documents/miniCRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES', probable reason 'Invalid argument'
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are these `<path>` variables just placeholders, or you're actually running that on your console? Also why use `file://` and not `file:/`?

Comment: They are just placeholders....the way they set up our accounts the name of my employer is in the path, so I just figured I'd play it safe.  
As for `file://` it was taken from an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905650/creating-a-local-r-package-repository) question